# How can I change the GNOME-Shell theme manually?

Tags: gnome, themes

I accidentally made GNOME-Shell unusable by testing a theme which completely broke the environment. After I've logged in nothing happens, all I get is an empty desktop.

I can't change the GNOME-Shell theme through gnome-tweak-tool when I'm not currently running the GNOME-Shell so how can I change this manually? There must be a value in gconf or something that I can edit to restore the shell, right?

Please help me out here? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get hold of a theme, if you don't got one you can find one [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/five-pretty-awesome-gnome-shell-themes/).
After you downloaded the theme, unzip it to "/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme".
Then you can reload gnome-shell by ALT+F2 and typing *gnome-shell --replace*
Or just log out and back in again.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you for the help, though I solved it by removing the GNOME-Shell user settings file in ~/.config/dconf/

I guess your way of solving it would be better since I needed to reconfigure all my personal settings after doing this but it worked at least :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name SHELL_THEME
```

Example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name Adwaita
```